# Determine the behavior of a function defined by an integral

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

Suppose we have a function defined by $$\varphi(s)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x,s)\,dx$$ defined for $s\in S\subseteq \mathbb{R}$. Suppose we know that it blows up at $a\in \partial S$, and we want to figure out the order of the function $\varphi$ as $s\to a$. How can we do that in general?

As a concrete example, there is a trick to determine that $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-sx^2}\,dx=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{s}}.$$
But suppose we didn't know that. How could we show that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-sx^2}\,dx$ was $O(s^{-\frac{1}{2}})$ at $s=0$?

**Ideas:** Taylor series, then integrating term by term, justifying with additional assumptions if necessary?

Comment: [These lecture notes](http://infohost.nmt.edu/~iavramid/notes.html) by Ivan Avramidi cover this topic briefly at the end of the first section.  I've also encountered a few problems like this which I could describe in an answer if you'd like.

Comment: @AntonioVargas Sorry, I'm not finding anything about this. In which section are they contained?

Comment: Whoops, I thought I linked directly to the notes!  Sorry about that.  They're the ones titled "Notes on Asymptotic Expansions", the 12th bullet point on the list.  In that document, see section 1.4.

Comment: @AntonioVargas Thank you, I will take a look at these